# Avoid FileChooser from opening again and again

Tags: javafx, stage, filechooser

If I press the button that activates this method() for example 3 times, it opens three Filechooser windows on top of each other and then cause nullpointer exceptions. How can I let it only open one at a time and then nothing happens if I click the button when Filechooser is open?

```
private void uploadImage() throws IOException { 
FileChooser chooser = new FileChooser(); //For the filedirectory
        Stage filechooser = new Stage();
        chooser.setTitle("Upload image");

        chooser.getExtensionFilters().addAll(
                new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter( "All Images", "*.jpg","*.jpeg","*.png","*.bmp","*.gif","*.wbmp" ),
                new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter( "JPG", "*.jpg" ),
                new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter( "JPEG", "*.jpeg" ),
                new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter( "PNG", "*.png" ),
                new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter( "BMP", "*.bmp" ),
                new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter( "GIF", "*.gif" ),
                new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter( "WBMP", "*.wbmp" )
        );
        this.imageChosen = chooser.showOpenDialog(filechooser); 
        this.filename = imageChosen.getName(); 
        System.out.println(this.imageChosen.getAbsolutePath());
        image.setImage(new Image("File:" + this.imageChosen.getAbsolutePath()));
}
```

Comment: Basically, don't create some random `Stage` and pass it to `showOpenDialog`. Pass the `Stage` to which the `Button` belongs.